# Google cloud - does anyone know how to deploy a node js app to a node js instance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Google cloud - does anyone know how to deploy a node js app to a node js instance.

I have a project with a node js instance running and I have a node js app.

I just need to know how to add the node js app to the cloud so I can navigate to my apps url routes.

Comment: There seems to be a [Node.JS wrapper](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) library for GCM. Would this take care of your requirement?

Comment: What's the wrapper do?

Comment: Its basically a web app that already uses GCM in this case.

Comment: All I need is to know how to put my node app onto my vm instance that I've made?

Comment: I'm having trouble deploying following the hello world tutorial that they have

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud has very good documentation and to answer your question, you can follow the [Quick Starter Guide](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) for a Hellow World App.

It's very simple and you can get it running in very few steps.

Disclaimer: I've no affiliation with Google nor Google Cloud, I'm just a happy customer.